# how to create email addreses for directadmin users

Tags: centos, email, squirrelmail

In directadmin reseller level when I create a user they can access their inbox through squirrelmail. they can send emails but they can't receive any because there isn't any address. for example when I sent an email to my Yahoo mail. sender's address was testmail@164.35 that i can't reply to it. every user has a different domain so email addresses should be based on their domain. e.g. john@jdomain.com, mike@mdomain.com

I have centos installed and as you know with directadmin control panel.

How can I create emails like I explained??

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a 'pop3 account' via the DirectAdmin email menu, it should create a new mail account, with a login of username@domain.com

It depends on your exim (DA default), squirrel mail or MUA settings, how the from address is set.

Can you post the headers from the email you received at yahoo, it may provide some insight.

You might also try to find the log entries of the outgoing email in /var/log/exim/mainlog (or the rotated version of that, if it is old, probably easiest to just send a fresh email)

If you are only a reseller, and don't have access to debug this, you should likely contact the people that own the box, and have them investigate.